# Item to Item recommendation engine on Google Cloud

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine, google-cloud-ml

I found an implementation of the recommendation engine on Google Cloud [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-overview), which turned out to be the **User to Item** recommendation.

I was wondering whether there is the similar solution for Google Cloud with **Item to Item** recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the **User** with **Item** data. Treat Item as User component. I guess rest of the things remains same in the SVD Matrix.